# Filling html input element and submitting form

Tags: c#, html, .net, http, webclient

I am trying to submit my twitter login and password with c# and some http code.

I have this html code:

```
<div class="row password error">
  <label for="password" tabindex="-1">Password</label>
  <input aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" autofocus="autofocus" class="password text" id="password" name="session[password]" type="password" value="" />
</div>
```

And I am trying to make the response in this way:

```
var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
var postData = ("password=" + Social); 
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;     
var newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
newStream.Close();

var response = myRequest.GetResponse();
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
var result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

return result;
```

But as you can see the name from input control is session[password], maybe is that the problem, if so, how can I input correctly the password and submit this form.

UPDATE Fiddle results: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AcG8HUKj
Thanks.

Comment: `name="session[password]"` this looks rather strange not to mention I think that you need to be using `asp directives such as `<% %>`

Comment: I dont own the page(twitter), I am acessing it from a desktop application.

Comment: ok then.. have you stepped thru the actual code on your end to inspect the values etc... are you getting any errors on your end when stepping thru the code..?? and also it's not about having access to their page or not .. if you wrote the aspx markup..then you should know and or understand how to use the proper tags as I was asking in my initial question... another thing is where are you passing in the credentials that seems to be the issue here I would do a bit more research on how to pass in user password credentials to a Twitter account using C# .net

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I am trying to make login with c# code, simple as that. You dont have to worry with nothing more. It is like I am building an robot and it will read the html code and input the right code, ok? There is no aspx markup what soever. The error as described, is the password being wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you inspecting HTTP traffic between the browser and the twitter website when you perform regular sign in using the browser. For example, using Fiddler.

Then inspect the request that you send from c# code, and compare to the request that was sent from the browser. Pay attention to headers and cookies. It may be that some kind of handshake is required.

Comment: It seems promising, let me try.